# What is wrong with this code? I'm trying to divide two values to get another value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to divide these values to get a number that represents opens to sent messages.

Here is the error I keep getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6"

```
SELECT opens / sent
FROM (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Email_Open_Table AS opens
        WHERE open_time <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '14' DAY)
        )
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Email_Send_Table AS sent
        WHERE send_time <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '14' DAY)
        )
    )
```

Comment: I think you're missing an end parenthesis at the end. Try adding a `)` to the end of the line and see if you still get that error.

Comment: Can't help feeling you're making it unnecessarily complicated. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`opens` and `sent` are the aliases of the tables inside the subqueries and not the returned values of the subqueries.
You can do the division directly like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Email_Open_Table WHERE open_time <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '14' DAY)) 
/ 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Email_Send_Table  WHERE send_time <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '14' DAY))
AS result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, thanks!

```
SELECT(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Email_Open_Table WHERE open_time between adddate(now(),-14) and now()) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Email_Send_Table WHERE send_time between adddate(now(),-14) and now()) AS open_rate
```

Comment: Since you are new here SO take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399